# Why doesn’t highlight-regexp highlight my regexp?

Tags: highlighting

When I evaluate `(highlight-regexp "todo" "hi-blue")` in a buffer, “todo” gets highlighted in that buffer.
I’d like “todo” to be highlighted in any buffer, always.

I’ve tried putting the following code in my Aquamacs Preferences.el file (equivalent to Emacs’ .emacs), based on what I read [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/highlighting-by-word-line-regexp):

```
(global-hi-lock-mode 1)
(setq hi-lock-file-patterns-policy (lambda (dummy) t))
(highlight-regexp "todo" "hi-blue")
```

But “todo” doesn’t get highlighted. What am I missing?

Comment: You can remove the `#'`.

Comment: @drew Thanks, I removed it so as not to set a bad example.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the hihglight-regexp does not work, but to get TODO highlighted in any buffer I recommend using the [hl-todo](https://melpa.org/#/hl-todo) package.

You do not have to 'sharp quote' a lambda expression as it is self-quoting (see 'lambda' docstring).

Answer (score 2):

`highlight-regexp` does its thing in the current buffer which likely is not set when `Preferences.el` is read.  To achieve the desired effect in every buffer, you need to call it in some hook that is fired when buffers are created but I do not know a good candidate.

Comment: `find-file-hook` perhaps?

Comment: You probably had found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899949/is-there-an-emacs-hook-that-runs-after-every-buffer-is-created) and answers already, but I think indeed `after-change-major-mode-hook` probably makes a good choice. However, I would still recommend to use the hl-todo package.